# Android pre-market publish (legal) questions

Tags: android, publish

1. I live in a country outside the supported countries of google to sell applications on the android market. Despite this I want to sell my apps on the market (pls don't suggest other appstores, like amazon). I thought I obtain an american IP (is that legal? there are plenty of websites selling US IP-s) and registrate as if i lived in the US. Does google accept it (they don't have to know that I am from a different country)?
   What do you think?
2. I also read that i have to registrate as a business when I want a google merchant account? I am a simple person who wants to sell his application. I don't own a business, or a firm. I have an active paypal account, that's all. What should I do?
3. I also read that after I created the merchant account and set my country, I cannot change it later. But what if I move abroad (I am planning to)?
4. If I want to create a website for my apps (it is not compulsory, right?), can I use an image of a phone? Or do I have to contact e.g. HTC for a picture that I can download from their site, or google?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm sure Google will find out. This could get you banned or maybe worse, I suggest not doing it.
2. You DONT need to create a google merchant account. Yo DO need to create a google Checkout account. The checkout account is needed for google to deposit payments on. This account is then linked to your bank account and every month google will deposit your earnings on your bank account. For Google Checkout, have a look here: https://checkout.google.com/sell
3. I do not know about this, sorry.
4. You can always use a "generic phone image" if you want to use an image of a phone per-se, but I think you are allowed to take an image of say an HTC desire, just mention at the bottom of your page that it contains content made by HTC or somethign similar and not claim it your own. I'm not 100% sure about this though. I know there is a google site about branding here: http://www.android.com/branding.html But it doesnt say anything about phone images.

Comment: 2. So i need only a google checkout account to get payments for my app?

Answer (score 1):

1. Nope you can't do it. Google will find it out when you submit your
   credit card details etc. So don't attempt it. if you don't like
   other app stores then you may give a try to some third party app
   brokers. They'll sell the app on your behalf on Android Market and
   share the revenue with you.
2. No need to have a business. there are hundreds of indivuduals selling apps on appstore so don't worry much about it. You can make your google check out merchant account if you are from accepted country.
3. PayPal also having same policy. You gonna have to delete your account and re-create one. I'm not sure whether Google check out imposes such policy.
4. As far as I know there wont' be much issue as you are not stealing atnything from HTC. But you can simply drop a mail to HTC customer care and see how they respond. Else you can use some generic Android Phone mock ups. If you are referring to the app screen shot only (only the LCD display) then don't worry. You are the one created it, you can use it on your will.

Comment: You mean when I want to create a google account I have to add my credit card number (seen on a video). Cannot I add my paypal account number? That's so unfair that a lot of people cannot make money of their apps just because their country is not supported!

Comment: You have to add yoru credit card for one time $25 charge. Nope no paypal.